Deriving influence function for doubly robust counterfactual density
I am currently reading the paper "Semiparametric Counterfactual Density Estimation" written by Edward Kennedy et al.
I encounter some issues reading proofs in the paper.
Especially, I have no idea on how to derive the following influence function.
enter image description here
Can anyone provide derivation for the formula?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.
